# Blender 2.8: UV-Editor Sticky Selection Mode Option gone?

Tags: uv-image-editor

[image: Sticky Selection in 2.79]

I need to move some points on my UV-map, but they are locked in Shared Location Mode, so I cannot move them independently. Where is the Sticky Selection Mode dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: UV-Layout Tab]
[image: Sticky Selection 2.8]

It shows up when the UV-Layout is selected. I have noticed this behavior when opening files that were written with older blender versions. In each of those cases, **using one of the default layouts restored visibility of the missing UI input fields**.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but had the same problem and found a solution. The box for the sticky selection disappears if you turn off UV sync selection. That was why I could not find it

Comment: Confused because when I turn off UV selection it shows the Sticky Selection mode button, but then the UV overlay disappears so then you can't edit the UV? In blender 3.6.2